# GIt push shows bad boolean config value error

Tags: github, git-push

I am trying to push a commit to a github branch. I forked the branch from the parent project. But everytime I do I am facing this error.

fatal: bad boolean config value 'https://github.com/Enan511/Internship-2024-Tech-Team-2.git' for 'push.autosetupremote'

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution after a bit enquiry. So what I did to solve this was:

> git config --get-all push.autosetupremote

Then it showed result:

> true

> true

Then I used command:

> git config --global --unset-all push.autosetupremote

After which the issue was solved, and I was able to push my commits without any further hassle. If anyone is also facing the same issue, hope this helps you.